# Whats Wrong with datetime on August 9, 2011?

Tags: telerik-mvc

suddenly got error on this :

```
@(Html.Telerik().Calendar()
        .Name("Calendar")
        .Value(DateTime.Now)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: auto;" })
)
```

it's work nice before today.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug. Go download a newer version.